# Laravel joins including where there is no match

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have a table layout like so:

```
products
    id
    productname

product_weights
    id
    productid
    weight

product_flavours
    id
    productid
    flavour
```

I am trying to generate a list of all possible product variations. Some products have no variation in size, some have no flavour variation, some have both. My current thinking is using a join. I have so far for my query:

```
DB::table('product_weights')
        ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'product_weights.prodid')
        ->select('product_weights.value', 'products.productname')
        ->get();
```

This gives something kind of useful, var_dump giving:

```
[{"value":"1kg","productname":"Item 1"},{"value":"2.1kg","productname":"Item 2"},{"value":"250g","productname":"Item 3"},{"value":"1kg","productname":"Item 3"}
```

The issue is that a product `item 5` with no weight variations is not returned. And of course I need to build in flavours too.

I then want to just make an array like {'Item 1 1kg', 'Item 2 2.1kg', 'Item 3 250g', 'Item 3 1kg'}

Any ideas? I kind of feel like I am doing the join wrong. Help would be appreciated!

**Update:** Thanks to comments below, some progress has been made with `leftJoin`. I can produce the desired results for weight or flavour, but not both. The code now is:

```
$product_join_weights = DB::table('products')
    ->leftJoin('product_weights', 'products.id', '=', 'product_weights.prodid')
    ->select('products.productname', 'product_weights.value')
    ->get();

$product_join_flavour = DB::table('products')
    ->leftJoin('product_flavours', 'products.id', '=', 'productattributes.prodid')
    ->select('products.productname', 'product_flavours.value')
    ->get();
```

Any ideas how they can be combined?

Comment: `->leftJoin` perhaps.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Yes, thank you! LeftJoin helped a lot. My issue now is combining the two. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of combining the two arrays, why not just chain the joins together?

```
 $product_join = DB::table('products')
        ->leftJoin('product_weights', 'products.id', '=', 'product_weights.prodid')
        ->leftJoin('product_flavours', 'products.id', '=', 'productattributes.prodid')
        ->select('products.productname', 'product_flavours.value', 'products.productname', 'product_weights.value')
        ->get();
```

> Left Joins fetch a **complete** set of records from table1, with the
>   matching records in table2. The
>   result is NULL in the right side when no matching will take place.

http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-a-left-join.php

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simply double the left join...

something like this:

```
$product_weights_and_flavours  = DB::table('products')
   ->leftJoin('product_weights', 'products.id', '=', 'product_weights.prodid')
   ->leftJoin('product_flavours', 'products.id', '=', 'productattributes.prodid')
   ->select('products.productname', 'product_weights.value', 'product_flavours.value')
   ->get();
```